# GLM output says one thing, but glm graph says another, Simpson's Paradox?

Tags: r, regression, partial-effect

I am running a GLM to evaluate the influence of canopy cover and vegetation density on average black-globe temperature. I ran a simple glm, but when I plot the model output, the plot does not agree with the model results. Particularly, the positive relationship between temperature and vegetation density in the model output being shown as a negative relationship in the model plot. Any ideas as to what is going on? Is this a product of Simpsons' Paradox? Thanks

```
structure(list(Id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("A1", "A10", "A100", "A11", "A12", "A13", 
"A14", "A15", "A16", "A17", "A18", "A19", "A2", "A20", "A21", 
"A22", "A23", "A24", "A25", "A26", "A27", "A28", "A29", "A3", 
"A30", "A31", "A32", "A33", "A34", "A35", "A36", "A37", "A38", 
"A39", "A4", "A40", "A41", "A42", "A43", "A44", "A45", "A46", 
"A47", "A48", "A49", "A5", "A50", "A51", "A52", "A53", "A54", 
"A55", "A56", "A57", "A58", "A59", "A6", "A60", "A61", "A62", 
"A63", "A64", "A65", "A66", "A67", "A68", "A69", "A7", "A70", 
"A71", "A72", "A73", "A74", "A75", "A76", "A77", "A78", "A79", 
"A8", "A80", "A81", "A82", "A83", "A84", "A85", "A86", "A87", 
"A88", "A89", "A9", "A90", "A91", "A92", "A93", "A94", "A95", 
"A96", "A97", "A98", "A99", "B1", "B10", "B100", "B11", "B12", 
"B13", "B14", "B15", "B16", "B17", "B18", "B19", "B2", "B20", 
"B21", "B22", "B23", "B24", "B25", "B26", "B27", "B28", "B29", 
"B3", "B30", "B31", "B32", "B33", "B34", "B35", "B36", "B37", 
"B39", "B4", "B40", "B41", "B42", "B43", "B44", "B45", "B46", 
"B47", "B48", "B49", "B5", "B50", "B51", "B52", "B53", "B54", 
"B55", "B56", "B57", "B58", "B59", "B6", "B60", "B61", "B62", 
"B63", "B64", "B65", "B66", "B67", "B68", "B69", "B7", "B71", 
"B72", "B73", "B74", "B75", "B76", "B77", "B78", "B79", "B8", 
"B80", "B81", "B82", "B83", "B84", "B85", "B86", "B87", "B88", 
"B89", "B9", "B90", "B91", "B92", "B93", "B94", "B95", "B96", 
"B97", "B98", "B99"), class = "factor"), Temp_C = c(23.484, 23.388, 
23.677, 24.738, 24.738, 24.255, 32.704, 35.222, 28.456, 43.238
), Temp_F = c(74.2712, 74.0984, 74.6186, 76.5284, 76.5284, 75.659, 
90.8672, 95.3996, 83.2208, 109.8284), Type = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Long = c(-97.47462153, -97.47462153, 
-97.47462153, -97.47462153, -97.47462153, -97.47462153, -97.47462153, 
-97.47462153, -97.47462153, -97.47462153), Lat = c(26.58459955, 
26.58459955, 26.58459955, 26.58459955, 26.58459955, 26.58459955, 
26.58459955, 26.58459955, 26.58459955, 26.58459955), landcover_class5m = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Woody", "Grassland", 
"Bareground", "Water"), class = "factor"), can_cover1m = c(0.474885043425438, 
0.474885043425438, 0.474885043425438, 0.474885043425438, 0.474885043425438, 
0.474885043425438, 0.474885043425438, 0.474885043425438, 0.474885043425438, 
0.474885043425438), veg_density1m = c(14.3261538377175, 14.3261538377175, 
14.3261538377175, 14.3261538377175, 14.3261538377175, 14.3261538377175, 
14.3261538377175, 14.3261538377175, 14.3261538377175, 14.3261538377175
), X = c(2941332.22211244, 2941332.22211244, 2941332.22211244, 
2941332.22211244, 2941332.22211244, 2941332.22211244, 2941332.22211244, 
2941332.22211244, 2941332.22211244, 2941332.22211244), Y = c(651903.662642045, 
651903.662642045, 651903.662642045, 651903.662642045, 651903.662642045, 
651903.662642045, 651903.662642045, 651903.662642045, 651903.662642045, 
651903.662642045), DateTime = structure(c(1560884400, 1560886200, 
1560889800, 1560891600, 1560893400, 1560958200, 1560960000, 1560961800, 
1560963600, 1560965400), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Time = c("14:00:00", "14:30:00", "15:30:00", "16:00:00", 
"16:30:00", "10:30:00", "11:00:00", "11:30:00", "12:00:00", "12:30:00"
), Date = structure(c(18065, 18065, 18065, 18065, 18065, 18066, 
18066, 18066, 18066, 18066), class = "Date"), AvgTemp_C = c(37.4423161407767, 
37.4423161407767, 37.4423161407767, 37.4423161407767, 37.4423161407767, 
37.4423161407767, 37.4423161407767, 37.4423161407767, 37.4423161407767, 
37.4423161407767), MedTemp_C = c(38.046, 38.046, 38.046, 38.046, 
38.046, 38.046, 38.046, 38.046, 38.046, 38.046), MaxTemp_C = c(46.083, 
46.083, 46.083, 46.083, 46.083, 46.083, 46.083, 46.083, 46.083, 
46.083)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(Id = structure(1L, .Label = c("A1", 
"A10", "A100", "A11", "A12", "A13", "A14", "A15", "A16", "A17", 
"A18", "A19", "A2", "A20", "A21", "A22", "A23", "A24", "A25", 
"A26", "A27", "A28", "A29", "A3", "A30", "A31", "A32", "A33", 
"A34", "A35", "A36", "A37", "A38", "A39", "A4", "A40", "A41", 
"A42", "A43", "A44", "A45", "A46", "A47", "A48", "A49", "A5", 
"A50", "A51", "A52", "A53", "A54", "A55", "A56", "A57", "A58", 
"A59", "A6", "A60", "A61", "A62", "A63", "A64", "A65", "A66", 
"A67", "A68", "A69", "A7", "A70", "A71", "A72", "A73", "A74", 
"A75", "A76", "A77", "A78", "A79", "A8", "A80", "A81", "A82", 
"A83", "A84", "A85", "A86", "A87", "A88", "A89", "A9", "A90", 
"A91", "A92", "A93", "A94", "A95", "A96", "A97", "A98", "A99", 
"B1", "B10", "B100", "B11", "B12", "B13", "B14", "B15", "B16", 
"B17", "B18", "B19", "B2", "B20", "B21", "B22", "B23", "B24", 
"B25", "B26", "B27", "B28", "B29", "B3", "B30", "B31", "B32", 
"B33", "B34", "B35", "B36", "B37", "B39", "B4", "B40", "B41", 
"B42", "B43", "B44", "B45", "B46", "B47", "B48", "B49", "B5", 
"B50", "B51", "B52", "B53", "B54", "B55", "B56", "B57", "B58", 
"B59", "B6", "B60", "B61", "B62", "B63", "B64", "B65", "B66", 
"B67", "B68", "B69", "B7", "B71", "B72", "B73", "B74", "B75", 
"B76", "B77", "B78", "B79", "B8", "B80", "B81", "B82", "B83", 
"B84", "B85", "B86", "B87", "B88", "B89", "B9", "B90", "B91", 
"B92", "B93", "B94", "B95", "B96", "B97", "B98", "B99"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))
```

```
middayglm <- glm(AvgTemp_C ~ can_cover1m + veg_density1m, data=midday)


Call:
glm(formula = AvgTemp_C ~ can_cover1m + veg_density1m, data = midday)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-7.6512  -0.8557   0.1114   0.9987   3.3244  

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   39.8968032  0.0066905 5963.17   <2e-16 ***
can_cover1m   -6.0778158  0.0150905 -402.76   <2e-16 ***
veg_density1m  0.0041058  0.0003364   12.21   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 2.473566)

    Null deviance: 1259787  on 256593  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  634695  on 256591  degrees of freedom
AIC: 960574

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

```
equation1 = function(x){coef(middayglm)[2]*x+coef(middayglm)[1]+coef(middayglm)[3]}

middayglm_plot <- ggplot(midday,aes(y=AvgTemp_C ,x=can_cover1m, color=veg_density1m)) +geom_point(size=8)+
  stat_function(fun=equation1,geom="line",size = 2,color='gray') +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red", na.value = NA,limits=c(0,100)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(25, 45, by = 5), limits=c(25,45)) +
  labs(title='Midday 09:00 - 16:59',x='% Canopy Cover', y='Average Temperature (C)', color='Vegetation Density')  +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=30),axis.title=element_text(size=30,face="bold"), 
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=30)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size=30), legend.text = element_text(size=20),
        legend.key.size = unit(2, 'cm')) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
middayglm_plot
```

[image: middayglm_plot]

Comment: +1. Just a heads up: Your posted dataframe does not correspond to the data in the model. `veg_density1m` and  `can_cover1m` are constant, for example.

Comment: Both ```veg_density1m``` and ```can_cover1m``` were collected at 100 individual thermometer sites. Within a given ```Id``` those measurements will not change and are replicated for every temperature measurement. ```deput(head(,10)``` only included one thermometer Id. I believe this is the issue. Thanks

Comment: It is also not clear what you think is wrong. You plot canopy cover on the x-axis, not vegetation density.

Comment: The model output shows a positive relationship between vegetation density and temperature. However, the graph shows a negative relationship. Vegetation density, represented by the color of the points, increases (becomes darker) as temperature decreases.

Comment: *equation1* is actually not a function for vegetation density. Or more precisely you have *coef(middayglm)[3]*  implicitly multiplied by veg_density1m = 1. The colors are "borrowed" from the midday data frame but otherwise don't have any effect.

Comment: You can't vary two predictors in a one-dimensional plot. You've make a partial effects plots for *veg_density1m = 1*.

Comment: @dipetkov that makes sense! I guess I should abandon this plot and look into a partial effects plot for each covariate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regression model has two predictors: *canopy cover* and *vegetation density*. In a 2D plot you can visualize the response, *temperature*, as a function of one predictor keeping the other fixed. This is called a partial effect plot. Note the connection to how regression coefficients are interpreted, in terms of change in the response *y* as a function of one unit change in predictor *x<sub>k</sub>* while holding the other variables in the model constant. Usually we choose "meaningful" values for the other predictors *x<sub>-k</sub>* such as the mean, median or mode.

Here is how to make a partial effect plot for canopy cover at three different vegetation indices. Not the most interesting plot because the relationships are linear and there are no interactions.

```r
library("tidyverse")

predict <- function(newdat) {
  # Hard-coded model. If the model object is available you can use
  # broom::augment(model_object, newdata = newdata)
  newdat %>%
    mutate(
      AvgTemp_C = 39.8968032 - 6.0778158 * can_cover1m + 0.0041058 * veg_density1m
    )
}

# Canopy cover seems to range from 0 to 1
# Vegetation density seems to range from 0% to 100%

# Let's create a grid of covariates (can_cover1m, veg_density1m).
# Then we use the model to generate predictions for point in the grid.
midday_grid <- crossing(
  # only need 2 points for a straight line
  # use more points if the relationship between can_cover1m and temperature is smooth
  can_cover1m = seq(0, 1, length.out = 2),
  veg_density1m = c(1, 50, 99)
)

midday_grid_with_preds <- predict(midday_grid)

# It's better to plot the raw data as well but I don't have access to it
# Instead I plot only the predicted relationship between canopy and temp
midday_grid_with_preds %>%
  ggplot(aes(can_cover1m, AvgTemp_C,
    group = veg_density1m,
    color = veg_density1m
  )) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: this is awesome! Thank you. Is ```dat``` the data.frame ```midday``` in my code? Also, you mentioned the raw data. Where do I input the raw data to plot it as well?

Comment: Updated the R code, now with more comments. By raw data I mean just to add the actual observations in midday (as you've done in your own plot) and then overlay the predicted lines.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Do you know why my code was creating labeling groups within the points themselves (by color) instead of drawing separate lines for each like you did?

Comment: I have a good idea: You have *ggplot(midday, aes(...)) + stat_function(fun=equation1)*. So this means that rather than a grid you use the original data *midday* and you evaluate *equation1* at all points in *midday*. These points have *veg_density1m* so you can color them by it even though *veg_density1m* is not used in *equation1*. So the concept to understand is the difference between the raw data *midday* and new data like *midday_grid*.

Comment: Makes sense. Is it possible to easily input those 3 trend lines into the ggplot I have created above? While keeping the data points and graph settings.

Comment: You can apply *stat_function* three times, say with fun = *equation1*, *equation50* and *equation99* where the number indicates the fixed value for *veg_density1m* and you should be able to get the same result. It's more unwieldy though. [And obviously if you try this, don't forget to actually specify the *veg_density1m* value.]

Comment: Thanks so much!